# Looking for one word to describe 'not enough space in a building'

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I am looking for one word (ideally, a noun) to describe 'not enough space in a building', 'a lack of space'. Could I use 'narrowness' or is there a better word?

According to the Oxford Dictionary, 'narrowness' means:

the fact of measuring a short distance from one side to the other, especially in relation to length  (one of the meanings)

Is 'narrowness' only about the relation to length or could it be used in general about the space being too small?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Narrowness' doesn't convey what you're trying to say. I believe 'cramped' is the word you're looking for:

Cramped:
not having enough space or time:

- *a cramped room/house*
- *We have six desks in this room, so we're a little cramped (for space).*
- *I have a very cramped schedule.*

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cramped

(P.S. when you're looking for a word to describe something, it's an adjective you're looking for, not a noun.)

Comment: Thank you Kvsm! That is the word! P.S. Yes, I probably didn't formulate the description so well. In general, I know the difference between a noun and an adjective. I wanted to find a noun for the whole phenomenon, but an adjective will fit fine, too. Thank you!